# How to override child css class in parent react component using sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-css-modules

Trying to change background color of Toast container, the code below suppose to make this.
I dont know what I am missing but it doesnt work...

this is what I tried:

```
.toastError {
  margin-top: 15rem;// this works
  &.Toastify__toast--error {
    background: #bd362f !important;// this is is not...
  }
}
```

react component:

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
..
return (
<ToastContainer position="top-center"
          className={styles.toastError}
          autoClose={4000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
        />
```

margin-top effect the component but cant change the color, the element looks like below in browser :
[image]

What do I need to do make it work?

Comment: You forgot the space here between the ampersand and the class `&.Toastify__toast--error`

Comment: @Martin thanks but doesnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use cssLoader with css modules, right? maybe you must mark `.Toastify__toast--error` as global. [Scoping classnames in cssLoader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#scope)

```
.toastError {
  margin-top: 15rem;

  :global(.Toastify__toast--error) {
    background: #bd362f !important;
  }
}
```